# How to check if del key is pressed in listview win32

Tags: c++

```
if ((((LPNMHDR)lParam)->idFrom == IDC_LV))
{
    switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
    {
        case LVN_COLUMNCLICK:
            OnColumnClick((LPNMLISTVIEW)lParam);
            break;

        case NM_RCLICK:
            OnRowRMClick((LPNMLISTVIEW)lParam); 
            GetProcesses();
            break;

    }   
}
```

I have ListView and when I select row and press Del I want to remove that row. How can I detect that delete button is presed inside listview

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes but for some reason it doesn't  trigger.

Comment: Oh.  Must be a bug in the operating system then.

Comment: Cleaning solution and closing VS did the trick. Now LVN_KEYDOWN works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In message WM_NOTIFY, use this

```
case WM_NOTIY:

    if (((LPNMITEMACTIVATE)lParam)->hdr.code == LVN_KEYDOWN)
    {
           if (((LPNMLVKEYDOWN)lParam)->wVKey == VK_DELETE)
           {
    
           }
    }
    
    break;
```